# Magento: How to save in database a new column in the shopping cart

Tags: magento-1.7, database, shopping-cart

I've created a new field in database and adding a new column in shopping cart items grid. But I don't know how to save the value in the data base. If I write some value and click the update cart button that value desapears.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have to add a new column in the `sales_flat_quote_item` table (and in `sales_flat_order_item` if you want that value to appear in the order items...also in `sales_flat_invoice_item`, `sales_flat_shipment_item`, `sales_flat_creditmemo_item` is you want it for the corresponding entities).

Clear the cache.
Now you have to override the cart controller, specially this method `Mage_Checkout_CartController::_updateShoppingCart` and make it collect the values from your field and attach it to the quote item.

You may need to add something like this:

```
$envasesData = $this->getRequest()->getParam('envases');//replace envases with the input name
foreach ($cart->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item) {
     if (isset($envasesData[$item->getId()])) {
         $item->setData('envases', $envasesData[$item->getId()])->save(); //replace 'envases' with the table column name
     }
}
```

Now, if you want that field value carried over to the orders and other item types (invoice, creditmemo, shipment) you need to add this in a `config.xml` of one of your custom extensions inside the `<global>` tag

```
<fieldsets>
    <sales_convert_quote_item> <!-- this will move it from quote to order -->
        <envases> <!-- replace the tag name with the table column name if different -->
            <to_order_item>*</to_order_item>
        </envases>
    </sales_convert_quote_item>
    <sales_convert_order_item>
        <envases><!-- replace the tag name with the table column name if different -->
            <to_quote_item>*</to_quote_item> <!-- this copies it to the quote when pressing 'reorder' --> 
            <to_invoice_item>*</to_invoice_item><!-- this copies it to the invoice item --> 
            <to_shipment_item>*</to_shipment_item><!-- this copies it to the shipment item -->
            <to_cm_item>*</to_cm_item><!-- this copies it to the credit memo item -->
       </envases>
    </sales_convert_order_item>
</fieldsets>
```

Comment: I just want the shopping cart page copy in which user can't proceed to checkout. Instead of checkout i will create request for quote for selected item i.e submitted by user from product view page.